# Storing Different Types of Assessments - JSON, Morph, or separate models?

Tags: mysql, laravel

My app is for teachers, recording test scores, assigning advice and making feedback comments. I have an Assessment model that stores StudentID and TeacherID, as well as a numerical 'Total'.  I then have various models that extend this for each type of assessment that we conduct, each with their own table.

e.g.
AssessmentBanana

- AssessmentID (one to one)
- Q1 (numerical, out of 4)
- Q2 (numerical, out of 34)
- Q3 (numerical, out of 40)
- Q3 AdviceStatementID (id linked to a table of pre-written advice)
- Q3 AdviceStatementOverride (text allowing the teacher to manually write advice)
- Comment

My problem is that every time we want to introduce a new type of assessment (say AssessmentApple, with 6 numerical marks all out of 8 and two different types of comment), I have to manually create a new database table, a new model and update various bits of code.

This is impractical and ideally, ultimately, I want teachers to be able to define their own assessments rather than hard coding it all.

I've considered having a single Assessment model instead and storing the question-by-question breakdown in a chunk of JSON, but I've heard about all of the issues that can create.  I've been recommended to look into morphing, but I'm not sure what that would look like in my specific case.  Would it be like this?

AssessmentType

- 1: Banana
- 2: Apple

Assessment

- AssessmentTypeID
- One to Many Scores
- One to Many AdviceStatements

Scores

- AssessmentTypeID
- StudentID
- ScoreName/Type (e.g. 'Question 4')
- Score (numerical score)

... with this last table serving as all the scores on all assessment records for all assessment types?

Is that a good design?  Where does polymorphism come in?  Is the JSON solution better?

Many thanks!